# maven-shade-plugin fails to work across multiple runs

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

The first time that `maven-shade-plugin` runs, it:

1. Uses foobar.jar as input
2. Outputs foobar-shaded.jar
3. Copies foobar.jar to original-foobar.jar
4. Copies foobar-shaded.jar to foobar.jar

This allows the `maven-install-plugin` to pick up the shaded JAR file and everyone is happy. Unfortunately, the second time you run the build the `maven-shade-plugin` now picks up the output from the first run as the input of the second run and you will end up with a slew of errors (e.g. overlapping classes/resources).

What is the easiest way to fix the plugin's behavior so it can be run over an over again without a `mvn clean` step?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest workaround is to instruct the JAR plugin to run even if the source files did not change. This will overwrite the shaded JAR and the `maven-shade-plugin` will do the right thing:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <configuration>
                <forceCreation>true</forceCreation>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```